# output HBase Increment in MR reducer

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, counter, increment

I have a mapreduce job that writes to HBase.  I know you can output `Put` and `Delete` from the reducer using the `TableMapReduceUtil`.

Is it possible emit `Increment` to increment values in an HBase table instead out emitting `Puts` and `Gets`?  If yes, how to do it and if not then why?

I'm using CDH3

```
public static class TheReducer extends TableReducer<Text, Text, ImmutableBytesWritable>  {  
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {         
        ///....DO SOME STUFF HERE
        Increment increment = new Increment(row);
        increment.addColumn(col,qual,1L);
        context.write(null, increment); //<--- I want to be able to do this                             
        }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can't use Increment in the context - but you can always open a connection to HBase and write Increments anywhere (mapper, mapper cleanup, reducer etc.)

Do note that increments are not idempotent so the result might be problematic on partial success of the map/reduce job and/or if you have speculative execution for M/R (i.e. multiple mappers doing the same work)

Comment: perhaps a 2nd question, but how would one disable speculative execution for a reducer using the java api?